# Concatenate the docID in SharePiont

Tags: document-library, calculated-column, document-set

Can the document ID column be concatenated and used in a calculated column to numbre items in sharepoint library? If yes, how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

**As a short answer:** NO

> The **ID** column is not a supported field in the **`calculated column`**.

For more details, check [The supported and unsupported columns in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

**As workaround solution**

- Create a SharePoint **Workflow** using SharePoint Designer as mentioned at [Using ID field in a calculated column in Sharepoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/08/30/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)